# Amazon cloudwatch metric filter by instance name

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

I'm trying to make an alarm to cpu usage for instances, some instances are regular ec2 and some are made in autoscaling. 
I'm looking for some kind of metric/dimension that can filter instances by tag : Name.
Is it possible, if yes than how? if no, how can I make it in different way?
Thanks,

Comment: please add ec2 tag so that it is easier to search.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, tag is not part of EC2 dimensions. The dimensions for EC2 are: 
 [AWS EC2 Dimensions and Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html)

One solution I can think of is:
1) get relevant instances by using tag filter by using the awscli command:  [Describe-Instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) .You can also filter output if you don't want to see all the fields for instance. But, atleast keep the basic info like instance-id,tag, instancetype etc. You can also use any language AWS SDK APIs to achieve the same. 
2) Then get the instance metrics using list-metrics.This will return all instances. 
3) Now use only the metrics of instances you got in 1). You can compare using instance-id. That is loop on the list got on 1) and compare the item with the ones in 2) using instance-id. Display the info if they match. You can put the results of 2) in a dict to make things fast i.e., O(n) instead of O(n^2).

If someone can give an even better better solution, then it is good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem here is with the autoscaling, the instances can dynamically change.

Comment: From what I know, you can list metrics of autoscaling separately using namespace: AWS/AutoScaling. You can also list metrics of EC2 using namespace AWS/EC2. So, you can get metrics in these two groups seperately and filter out to get only instances in EC2 and not in autoscaling. So, you will have 2 lists of metrics. One for autoscaling and one for non-autoscaling. Then you do the same as mentioned in the answer. Filter out only relevant instances.

Comment: If your question is to dynamically display this, then write a script which will do this for every 1 minute or whatever granularity you want and display the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by name, even if the instance ids change due to autoscaling they will still be available to use. I can't see what language you are using however in Java it would be something like.

```
// Create custom filter e.g name

Filter filterByName = new Filter();
filterByName.withName("tag:Name").withValues("Instance_1");

// Create Describe Instances Request
DescribeInstancesRequest instanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest()
        .withFilters(
          filterByName);
```

Notice that when you use a custom filter e.g name you have to use the tag keyword, seen above. AWS does have built in filters which are called resource attributes and can be seen on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html#withFilters-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Filter...-) link. However if the instances are changing dynamically due to autoscaling I would recommend doing it by name. This [blog post](https://i0nak.wordpress.com/2018/08/19/filtering-aws-resources-using-custom-tags/) may be useful to you.